# Can I create a dacpac including data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dacpac, bacpac

Can I create a DACPAC including data in SQL Server 2008?

My requirement is to generate the incremental script of the DB changes, would I be able to do that using BACPAC?

I tried reading this, but this is not much helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860455(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: A `DACPAC` **always** contains **only** the structure of the database. If you want the data, too - you need a `BACPAC`

Comment: my requirement is to generate the incremental script of the DB changes, would I be able to do that using BACPAC?. Also I read from this msdn url about including data in dacpac .https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860455(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: that 'extract data tier application' will contain a 'select data' option in the wizard, which isn't available for me

Comment: You can extract a .dacpac from a database. Extract creates a database snapshot file (.dacpac) from a live SQL Server or Windows Azure SQL Database that might contain data from user tables, in addition to the database schema - from MSDN

Comment: According to the [official MIcrosoft docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213241(v=sql.110).aspx) - no, this is a SQL Server **2012 and newer** only feature

Comment: I tried using SQL 2012 as well and i still dont find the option in the extract wizard. Is there any patch that needs to be installed for this option to be available

Comment: @Saranya, `Extract` creates a DACPAC (schema only) whereas `Export` creates a BACPAC (schema and data). A DACPAC may be used to generate an incremental deployment script to upgrade a database while retaining existing data in the target. A BACPAC can be used to create a new database with both schema and data. The [limitations state SQL Server 2005 SP4 or later is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/extract-a-dac-from-a-database).

Comment: @Saranya are you trying to mix DB structure changes and data changes into one? That would not work well and you will not find a good solution to this.

Comment: A BACPAC will only add data via bulk import; it will not modify existing data (through comparison or otherwise). It cannot be used to deploy incremental data modifications. The usual solution is to use pre- and post-deployment scripts for that.

Comment: You can use a DACPAC with pre & post deployment sql script files. The DACPAC can be used on databases with existing data, you just need to ensure you have the right defaults and constraints for new columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use **SqlPackage.exe** tool manually found actions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx).

Use Export action as:

```
sqlpackage.exe /action:Export /TargetFile:"test.bacpac" 
    /sourceDatabasename:test 
    /sourceservername:.\testserver
```

Use Extract action as:

```
sqlpackage.exe /action:Extract /TargetFile:"test.dacpac" 
    /sourceDatabasename:test 
    /sourceservername:".\testserver"
    /p::ExtractAllTableData=true
```

- Source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819681/how-to-include-data-in-a-dacpac)

> By default, data for all tables will be included in the **.bacpac** file.